# What are network port maps and what are they used for by the networking team in an organization?

Tags: networking, switchport

I am curious to know what information generally the port maps contain.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Right now your questions isn't really clear to me. There are at least three different types of port maps with regards to networking that I have come across in my career - patch panel ports (typically detailing what is connected to each port), wall ports (typically on a floor plan), or ephemeral ports (such as TCP or UDP ports allowed to transit various parts of a network infrastructure).

Comment: I wanted to know in general the various kinds and each of its purposes in detail.Generally I see from the answer that I was asked the patch panel ports mapping by network team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A port map is generally a listing of which patch-panel port is connected to which switch/router/firewall on which interface.  For example, something like: "Patch-Panel A port 11 is connected to Switch 1 on port Gi1/0/34".  While there are other types of port maps, I find that this is the most common use/form.